# Android: any tools instead of eclipse Emulator that install and test Android APK file?

Tags: testing, device, android-2.2-froyo, android

I have ready made android installation apk file. But i dont have android device available.

I know that i can run the Android apk file in to Emulator by using the eclipse and help of the android sdk.

But other then it is there any other readymade tool that can install and run the apk file and to test the android app ?

If yes then what it is ? and how to get it ??

Thanks.

Comment: By "Eclipse emulator", do you mean the emulator that comes with the Android SDK?

Comment: Yes, i means that. But i dont want to use it. But use another tools. Instead of that eclipse. And i just concern with the testing of the apk file. i dont want any development tool.

Comment: why not you use deviceanywhere, it provides a variety of devices to test your application.

Comment: Just for information, it is not from Eclipse but from Android/Google. The eclipse plugin only allows you to use them from the Eclipse GUI but it is not a different product.

Comment: Ok Thanks. B ut i need any readymade tool that works like android Emulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all,
After some time, i got answer of this question.

YES, You can able to test the apk file by your own without installing the Eclipse.

[YouWave](http://youwave.com/) is the Solution of that question.

You can easily get install the apk file in to Android Like Device and also run it quickly. Even YouWave also run very fast like real device. You must have to try it once.

So, Enjoy your apk testing with the YouWave.

Enjoy. :)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Genymotion. www.genymotion.com It's really fast and some cool features like simulation of battery, rotations and some others. Though, it's missing mobile network still...